# Regular Expression that will replace anything that wouldn't be valid in a jQuery selector with an underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I ran into an issue where I need to clean up a bunch of HTML Element IDs so that they will always work when used as a **jQuery** selector i.e. `$("My_Element_Id")`. The Element IDs I am dealing with have all kinds of characters in them such as White Spaces, `% / \ . :` and so on..

I believe in jQuery as long as you replace white spaces and escape any other special characters with a backslash it should work, but in my scenario I would just like to replace all special characters with underscores.

The goal is to create a regular expression that will replace anything that would not be valid when using in a jQuery selector with an _

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for. Maybe add a few samples and their expected outputs. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to handle invalid ids would be to do something like `$('*[id="My Element Id"]')`

Comment: @MattBurland Slight correction :) Actually if you try to do `$('*[id="="]')`, it should throw a exception but it does not. The `$('#=')` on the other hand throws it.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: That's kinda the point. If you have an element with an id of `=` (as dumb as that is), you can still select it with `$('*[id="="]')`. Sometimes you can't change the dumb crap somebody else has done with HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, jQuery selectors can only be alpha numeric with underscores and hyphens. However, they are still just CSS selectors, which you can escape in jQuery. For example, the CSS selector `foo.bar` would be used as `$("foo\\.bar")`. But let's just replace them as your question asks.

Given that we know it can only be alphanumeric, hyphens and underscores (correct me if I am wrong), we can do some simple regex:

`/[^A-Z0-9_]/`

```js
var invalid1 = "foo.bar";
var invalid2 = "foo//bar";

var correct1 = invalid1.replace(/[^A-Z0-9_-]/ig, "_");
var correct2 = invalid2.replace(/[^A-Z0-9_-]/ig, "_");

console.log(correct1);
console.log(correct2);
```

This basically replaces anything that isn't alphanumeric or an underscore with an underscore.

The `g` modifier makes sure it matches all occurrences, `i` means case insensitive.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, a hyphen is a valid character so I added that to the regex.

Comment: `-` is also considered as a valid character.